# Joomla - get table timestamp through MVC component model

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to get the last modified time stamp from a joomla table.  I'm trying to pull it through a model function.

```
function timeStamp() {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "
        SELECT UPDATE_TIME
            FROM   information_schema.tables
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'singleprop'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'jos_mls'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $timestamp = $db->loadResult();
    return $timestamp;
}
```

Does Joomla offer a way to do this outside of what I've tried to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was this:

```
function timeStamp() {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "
        SELECT information_schema.`TABLES`.UPDATE_TIME
            FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
            WHERE information_schema.`TABLES`.TABLE_NAME =  'jos_mls';";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $timestamp = $db->loadResult();
    return $timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/database/query.php#L726  i.e. getCurrenttimestamp().

Comment: No, that's the current timestamp, not the timestamp of when the specified table was last modified.

Like most things, it was a syntax error on my part.  I never closed off the `$query` variable.

Comment: Oh sorry read too quickly. No I don't think there is anything like that in the platform. Would be great to have.